# SQL get count from one table and split to two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Date        Product
1/1/2015    Apples
1/1/2015    Apples
1/1/2015    Oranges
1/2/2015    Apples
1/2/2015    Apples
1/2/2015    Oranges
```

How can I do a select so I get something like this:

```
Date      Count of Apples    Count of Oranges
1/1/2015      2                 1
1/2/2015      2                 1
```

Thanks. I have tried case like this but the error is being thrown:

```
Select 'Date',
CASE WHEN 'Product' = 'Apples' THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END as 'Count'
FROM #TEMP Group by 1,2
```

Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Several mistakes here. First is the use of quotes. They are for strings. E.g. the string 'Product' will never match the string 'Apples'. The column is just Product without quotes. An alias name can have quotes, but double quotes then: "COUNT" not 'COUNT'. Then you cannot use positions in GROUP BY, you need columns. Then you want to group by date alone, because it's one record per date you want to see in your results.

Comment: Then when having an aggregate (`COUNT(*)`) inside `CASE WHEN` then the aggregation happens first. So you say when the string 'Product' equals 'Apples' then give me the count, else 0, because you mistakenly used quotes around Product. But once you remove the quotes and change 'Product' to Product, so as to check whether a product is an apple, then it's to late, because you did the aggregation already, so you are not looking at single products anymore.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation like this:

```
select 
  [date], 
  sum(case when Product = 'Apples'  then 1 else 0 end) as [Count of Apples],
  sum(case when Product = 'Oranges' then 1 else 0 end) as [Count of Oranges]
from #temp
group by [date]
```

Comment: Rob dont use a variable name `date` because that is a reserved word. You can use it betwen bracket like `[date]` but still isnt recomended, name it something like `ProductDate`

Answer (score 1):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select date, 
       sum(case when Product = 'Apples' then 1 else 0 end) as Apples,
       sum(case when Product = 'Oranges' then 1 else 0 end) as Oranges,
from table
group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not accept column references in the `GROUP BY`.  So, "1" and "2" refer to, well, the numbers one and two.

However, you seem to be confusing string constants and columns.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  I suspect that `Date` and `Product` are the names of columns.  So, the query you probably want is a conditional aggregation:

```
Select Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Product = 'Apples' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumApples
FROM #TEMP
Group by Date
Order by Date;
```